# O que significa o operador === em Kotlin?

Tags: operadores, kotlin

O que significa o operador === do Kotlin, e como usar? Encontrei esse trecho de código na documentação, mas fiquei com dúvidas.

```
val boxedA: Int? = a
val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a
println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // !!!Prints 'false'!!!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ele é usado para verificar a igualdade referencial, ou seja, se as referências contidas nas duas variáveis são a mesma, portanto apontam para o mesmo endereço e então o mesmo objeto, o que obviamente que a igualdade de valor será igual também.

No seu exemplo você tem objetos com o mesmo valor, mas eles são objetos totalmente diferentes. O `Int?` é um tipo por referência então cada variável tem um objeto diferente. Se fosse só o `Int` seria diferente.

Ele é usado em oposição ao `==` que só analisa o valor do objeto, então é possível que dois objetos diferentes em locais diferentes sejam iguais se a análise da sua estrutura for igual. A maneira como esses valores são verificados depende de cada objeto e pode ser personalizado no tipo que você cria. Há casos que a igualdade simples, ou estrutural na verdade é igual à referencial, mas é só porque o tipo estabeleceu assim. Isso tem a ver com identidade do objeto.

A [documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) fala isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).